# laravel 5.1 custom validation message same field name

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have in my application fields with the same name accross my models. For example I have a "firstname" field in both User Model and Teacher Model. I am using validation and specified custom validation messages in Language files (by adding language folders and validation.php files inside resources/lang). Is there a way to return different messages for same field name? For example i would like to do something like the following

```
'custom' => [ 
                'user.firstname' => [
                       'required' => 'message',            
                 ],
                 'teacher.firstname' => [
                       'required' => 'different message',            
                 ],
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass custom error messages to the Validator.
See (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

so your messages array would be looking something like this:

```
 $messages = [
     'required' => trans('validation.error1')
 ];
```

you could even specify a different require message for every input with this notation:

```
'email.required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser. I am not using the validate method inside my controllers and it would be very time consuming to transfer it in my controllers. I am working with the language files and I am looking for a solution in this case (check Specifying Custom Messages In Language Files in your link) . It would be much faster for me just to alter field names accros models in order to be unique.